# Nav isn't sticking to the top at widths less than 1025px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I'm using Wordpress and Foundation to build a site. I have a nav bar that I'd like to fix to the top of the page once it hits the top of the window. However, the nav is not sticking to the top at widths that are smaller than 1025px and I'm not getting any console errors. Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var distance = $('.mainContent').offset().top

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= distance) {
      $("#nav_bar").addClass("fixedtop");
    } else  {
      $("#nav_bar").removeClass("fixedtop");
    }
  })
});
```

CSS

```
.fixedtop {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 999;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: "not working" is not a clear problem statement.  Please explain what is "not working" about it.

Comment: The nav isn't sticking to the top like the function is being told to do. I apologize about that

Comment: Your logic seems fine, I can only surmise that there's something in your CSS which is affecting the `.fixedtop` class. You may need to check `distance` within the `scroll`, to ensure that the top of the targeted element has not moved, and also that it's still flows in the DOM.

Comment: So, troubleshoot the _javascript_, first.  Your script actually **does not** tell the nav to stick to the top, it _adds a class_.  Is it doing that? (If you don't know, then check out how to use your Browser's Developer Console, and inspect the element to see).

Comment: It adds the class only above 1025px but I'm not getting any Console errors, I've checked all media queries and I'm not finding any issues there.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it in inspector and only above the width of 1025px does that class get added.

Comment: Changed the class name to .fixedtop1 and the id to #nav_bar1 still didn't work.

Comment: I threw some alerts in the _if_ and the _else_ conditions. I only got an alert in the _else_

Comment: So - what is `distance`?  Maybe the narrower viewport causes it to be too large?

Comment: at 1025 it's 600 and 1024 its 599. But what do I do to fix the issue with that information?